# how to make root to mobile Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo GT-19060 on Ubuntu for upgradation

Tags: android

I am trying to upgrade Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo GT-I9060 from Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean to Android 5.1 Lolipop or more latest version on Ubuntu 15.10. How to make root it.  Please anybody can provide commands to run on terminal and upgrade it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install Heimdall, it's an open source alternative to Odin - `sudo apt-get install heimdall-flash-frontend`. Then - `sudo heimdall-frontend`.

Most likely, you can flash new frmware from sd-card.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to install and upgrade, but I could not get ROM firmware .zip file for up gradation.